# MongoDb / Lookup + Update documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

Can you please help for my problem ?
I have 2 documents : suppliers and consolidation.
I need to update consolidation document with suppliers fields (consolidation.frs_codeclient from supplier.codeclient and consolidation.frs_price from supplier.price) only if consolidation.frs_code = supplier.code AND consolidation.etb_code = suppplier.customer_code.

Below, my script but that does not work :(

```
exports.build = (req, res) => {
  console.log("Build consolidation");
  Consolidation.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {
      from: 'suppliers',
      as: 'Supplier',
      let: { 
        SupplierCode: '$code',
        SupplierCustomerCode: '$customer_code',
        SupplierCodeClient: '$codeclient',
        SupplierPrice: '$price'
      },
      pipeline: [
        { $match:
          { $expr: {
            $and: [
              { $eq: ['$frs_code', '$$SupplierCode'] },
              { $eq: ['$etb_code', '$$SupplierCustomerCode'] }
            ]
          }}
        },
        { $project: { 
          frs_codeclient: "$$SupplierCodeClient", frs_price: "$$SupplierPrice"
        }}
      ]
    }}
  ])
  .then(data => {
    res.send({
      message: `${data.deletedCount} Consolidations were built successfully!`
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message:
        err.message || "Some error occurred while building all Consolidations."
    });
  });
};
```

Thank you for your help :)

**UPDATE**

I found with this solution :

```
db.customers.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {
      from: "suppliers",
      let: { 
        customerCode: "$code",
        customerName: "$name",
        customerCodePostal: "$codepostal",
        customerCity: "$city",
        customerPrice: "$price",
        customerSupplierCode: "$supplier_code",
        customerSupplierCodeClient: "$supplier_codeclient"
      },
      pipeline: [
         { $match:
          { $expr: {
            $and: [
              { $eq: ["$customer_code", "$$customerCode"] },
              { $eq: ["$code", "$$customerSupplierCode"] }
            ]
          }}
        },
         { $project: { 
          _id: 0,
          "supplierCode": "$code",
          "supplierName": "$name",
          "supplierCodeClient": "$codeclient",
          "supplierCustomerCode": "$customer_code",
          "supplierPrice": "$price",
          "customerCode": "$$customerCode",
          "customerName": "$$customerName",
          "customerCodePostal": "$$customerCodePostal",
          "customerCity": "$$customerCity",
          "customerPrice": "$$customerPrice",
          "customerSupplierCode": "$$customerSupplierCode",
          "customerSupplierCodeClient": "$$customerSupplierCodeClient"
        }}
      ],
      as: "supplier"      
    }},
    { $project: { 
          _id: 0,
          "price": 1,
          "supplierCode": "$supplier.supplierCode",
          "supplierName": "$supplier.supplierName"
        }}
])
```

Comment: I updated my post because I found a solution. I added it in original post. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the solution as an answer instead of part of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found with this solution :

```
db.customers.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {
      from: "suppliers",
      let: { 
        customerCode: "$code",
        customerName: "$name",
        customerCodePostal: "$codepostal",
        customerCity: "$city",
        customerPrice: "$price",
        customerSupplierCode: "$supplier_code",
        customerSupplierCodeClient: "$supplier_codeclient"
      },
      pipeline: [
         { $match:
          { $expr: {
            $and: [
              { $eq: ["$customer_code", "$$customerCode"] },
              { $eq: ["$code", "$$customerSupplierCode"] }
            ]
          }}
        },
         { $project: { 
          _id: 0,
          "supplierCode": "$code",
          "supplierName": "$name",
          "supplierCodeClient": "$codeclient",
          "supplierCustomerCode": "$customer_code",
          "supplierPrice": "$price",
          "customerCode": "$$customerCode",
          "customerName": "$$customerName",
          "customerCodePostal": "$$customerCodePostal",
          "customerCity": "$$customerCity",
          "customerPrice": "$$customerPrice",
          "customerSupplierCode": "$$customerSupplierCode",
          "customerSupplierCodeClient": "$$customerSupplierCodeClient"
        }}
      ],
      as: "supplier"      
    }},
    { $project: { 
          _id: 0,
          "price": 1,
          "supplierCode": "$supplier.supplierCode",
          "supplierName": "$supplier.supplierName"
        }}
])
```